# Saving and restoring of many flags(variables)

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm building an singleplayer adventure map, and need a bunch of "Flags"(a few hundred maybe), which are basically variables to indicate, whether the player has visited certian places/killed enemies, etc.

I can think of two ways to do this:

1. Scoreboard objectives
2. Blocks at specific positions

I would just use the scoreboard, but I want the player to be able to save/load the state of all flags(at once). With blocks, you could just use the `/clone` command, but scoreboards would require two commandblocks per flag to save and restore, whereas one `/clone` can copy up to 32768 blocks/flags at once.

**Scoreboard**

Advantages: Easy to set/check, because you can give names like visitedCityXYZ

Disadvantages: Very hard to copy/restore, because every flag would need 1 commandblock for saving and one for loading

**Blocks**

Advantages: Easy saving/loading with `/clone`

Disadvantages: Harder to set/check, because you would need to remember/look up the coordinates of every flag. The Chunk containing the blocks may unload, and all `/clone`, `/setblock` and `/testforblock` commands would fail.

**Main question**: Does anyone know a better way of building a "Flag"-system, which I can save/load, or an easier way to copy scoreboard values from/to the player.

Edit: I totally forgot, I could just put the blocks/containers into my Spawnchunk... I was placing commandblocks there to be always active, but didn't thought about using it for the flags.

Comment: I wonder if you can manage the flags as different kinds of items in a container, then clone/replace the container as save/load.

Comment: Very good idea, but this improves "my" block method only in terms of compression. My major point was, that the blocks could be in an unloaded chunk, producing unpredictable results. Using containers doesn't change that.

Comment: You can still have the clones of the chest "follow" the player between chunks (e.g. if the player moves more than several chunks distance, clone the chest to land under his current chunk). And it drops the need to remember hundreds of locations, just the "offset" of the "save chests".

Comment: Yeah, maybe I could use a marker-ArmorStand to track the chest, which again, tracks the player...

Comment: You might want to edit the title for the benefit of future readers. What you describe is not what is commonly called a ["state machine"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_machine) (i.e. an automaton that has rules to change between different states based on input stimuli). I'd rather call it "saving and restoring the state of many flags" or something similar.

Comment: @Fritz I changed the title. I also included `(variables)`, so nobody confuses flags with banners.

Comment: Good idea (I confused it first, too). Btw. you can also move your "Spawn Chunk" edit from your question into an answer. Answer your own question so to say. Maybe it will even get some upvotes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Store the values in armor stands and switch the armor stands' name when saving and loading a state.

The armor stands' name will be n, where N equals the id of the set. When using the data pull it from set 0 and when saving/loading switch the names of the desired set with set 0.

Switch sets:

```
/entitydata @e[type=ArmorStand,name=0] {CustomName:9999}
/entitydata @e[type=ArmorStand,name=<id of desired set>] {CustomName:0}
/entitydata @e[type=ArmorStand,name=9999] {CustomName:<id of desired set>}
```

Comment: Problably wasn't clear in my question, but i want to be able to load/save these flags like im saving a file. For example load the state, modify it a bit, and load it again, discarding the modifications. I edited the question. I don't want pre defined states to be loaded, like a gallery, but instead save/load a game state

Comment: So you want something that allows for reloading the same file right?

Comment: well, not really file, but the state of all flags(like a textfile for example)